# p:repeat partial update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I am using Primefaces 6.0 and the `p:repeat` component

I have an input component (specifically `p:calendar`) inside a `p:repeat`. What I want is this: when I select a date/time on a specific calendar, I need to update every calendar inside the repeat, apart from the one I edited/selected the date.

The reason I want this is because if I update the whole repeat (the panel wrapping it), every time the user selects a date the calendar disappears (understandably since it's re rendered). But because I allow my users to also select hours and minutes, it's bad from a UX perspective to have the need to reopen the calendar every time the user selects any of month/hours/minutes.

<s>As a workaround, is there a way to attach an event to the close button of the calendar, so I can do the processing after the user is done editing the date?</s>

Edit: Actually the close button event wont help because the user can just click outside of the popup.

Comment: _"As a workaround, is there a way to attach an event to the close button of the calendar, so I can do the processing after the user is done editing the date?"_: Sure, it is client-side all html, css and javascript. Just use a browser developer tool to find the component and creatively use a jquery selector to add an eventhandler

Comment: Check my edit, after a little thinking i believe this won't do the trick